Why my slider does not work in shiny app using a barplot?
I am using the WorldPhones dataset to understand how shiny inputs work.
I added a slider using the code below because I want to also filter by "Users", but the barplot is not showing.
filter(Users == input$Users)

I also tried to put the input inside the "aes", and the barplot appears but the bars are always of the same height.
 ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = input$Users))

Below you can see my code:
ui.R
library(datasets)
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

# Use a fluid Bootstrap layout
fluidPage(    
  
  # Give the page a title
  titlePanel("Telephones by country"),
  
  # Generate a row with a sidebar
  sidebarLayout(      
    
    # Define the sidebar with one input
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("Country", "Country:", 
                  choices=colnames(WorldPhones)),
      
      sliderInput("Users", "Number of Users", 
                  min = 0, max = 80000, value = 25000),
    ),
    
    # Create a spot for the barplot
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("phonePlot")  
    )
  )
)

server.R
library(datasets)
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)


# Define a server for the Shiny app
function(input, output) {
  
  # Fill in the spot we created for a plot
  output$phonePlot <- renderPlot({
    
    # Render a barplot
    WorldPhones %>%
      as.data.frame() %>%
      rownames_to_column("Year") %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = -Year, names_to = "Country", values_to = "Users") %>%
      filter(Country == input$Country) %>%
      filter(Users == input$Users) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Users)) +
      geom_col(fill = "steelblue") +
      labs(
        title = paste("Telephones in", input$Country),
        x = "Year",
        y = "Number of Telephones"
      ) +
      theme_minimal()
  })
}




Well, you are filtering the data frame to include only those observations with Users == 25000.  There are none.  Hence an empty plot.  And when you put ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = input$Users)), you are setting the y values of your plot to 25,000.  That's a constant.  Hence all your bars are the same height.  Perhaps you want filter(Users <= input$Users)?

unfortunately, it is not working

Unfortunately, “it’s not working” is not specific enough. As an aside, why have you asked essentially the same question as you did yesterday, and for which you accepted an answer?

It is not the same question because in this case I want to filter by users. Thanks anyway for your help.
